# Method that returns property VS property direct access in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, design-patterns, object, properties

I have found that many javascript developers create methods that simply return a property like this :

```js
function Obj (prop) {
    this.prop = prop; // public
}
Obj.prototype.getProp = function () {
    return this.prop;
};
```

While prop is public and can be accessed like this :

```js
var a = obj.prop;
```

Moreover, I found that accessing an object property with a method is 121 times slower than accessing it directly (in Firefox)

```js
var a, b,
    obj = new Obj(1);

a = obj.prop;
// ~6ns on Chrome
// ~5ns on Firefox

b = obj.getProp();
// ~6ns on Chrome (no difference)
// ~730ns on Firefox (122x slower...)
```

So my question is: should we always create methods that return properties or can we access properties directly? Is that antipattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's an antipattern. Since js doesn't have native getters and setters which will be crossbrowser, yet, you should create your own getters and setters like:

```
Obj.prototype.getProp = function () {
    return this.prop;
};
```

Yes, you still can access this prop directly, but now you doesn't have to. More on that. This way you can create private properties via closures:

```
function Foo() {
   var __yourPrivateProp = 'Bar';
   return {
           getyourPrivateProp: function () {
               return: __yourPrivateProp
           }
   };
}
```

Comment: *All modern* browsers support defining getters and setters (using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility), and older `__defineGetter__` / `__defineSetter__`).